# Kotlin: Access nested enum class from java

Tags: java, kotlin, interop

I'm trying to access a data class with embedded enum from java

```
data class MyStatus( val status: Status ) {
   enum class Status{ OK, ERROR }
}
```

Seems that Status is invisible if I use it from Java. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: make it public ;)

Comment: @VeselinDadidov It is ``public`` already since ``public`` is the *default* visibility modifier in Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there's no problem, just do 
`MyStatus s = new MyStatus(MyStatus.Status.ERROR);`

Here's what the compiler generates for your `Enum`:

```
public static enum Status {
  OK,
  ERROR;
}
```

It's nested in `MyStatus`.

Comment: That is what I've tried. But I did it in Eclipse with the Eclipse-Kotlin-Plugin which works not very well. I now tried it using IntelliJ and it works like expected.

Comment: The Eclipse-Plugin isn't maintained afaik. If you have the opportunity use IntelliJ ;-)

Comment: It's a little bit sad that using kotlin isn't ide independent. Our development policy is to use Eclipse. So it is impossibe to recommend kotlin to a wider audience. I unterstand that JetBrains want to promote their own ide. But that will slow down or stop the raise of kotlin.

Comment: Kotlin itself is ide independent. You can install the kotlin SDK And use kotlinc to compile. The Eclipse plugin for Kotlin is just that...a plugin. It adds Kotlin support to Eclipse. It sounds like it's just not as well maintained though.